# Eagle CAD default assembly variant

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, library

I got source files (.sch and .brd) but unable to use Add command to add components. The error message said:

> "The Add command can only be used in the default assembly variant!"

I can't modify at all. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: add command on schematic or on board? What exactly you want to add?....please be more specific!

Comment: What should we understand from this? It's not clear at all.

Comment: [Assembly Variants](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-assembly-variants/)

Comment: I use add command on schematic. I want to modify some parts on the original design. This error message blocks me to access library to pick components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself the answer. Just simply set the main assembly variants to blank state (it's located next to the mark question on the toolbar. Hope that help!